# ListBox items doesn't appear when I get it from Method

Tags: c#

I have problem with `ListBox`.

I made a method that does some work and returns a `ListBox` type.  I tried to get this `Listbox` instance from the method, but the `ListBox` doesn't show any items.

I hope to know how I can replace the existing `ListBox` with the returned `Listbox` from the method.

```
    public ListBox GetProduct()
    {
        ListBox MyListBox = new ListBox();
        MyListBox.Sorted = true;
        MyListBox.Items.Add("aaaaa");

        return MyListBox;
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1 = GetProduct();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public void GetProduct(ListBox MyListBox)
{

    MyListBox.Sorted = true;
    MyListBox.Items.Add("aaaaa");

}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    GetProduct(listBox1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but Is there another way to pass returned type?

Comment: basically yes, but it makes no sense in this case. controls can be created and inserted into a form dynamically, but you should try the upper easier solution first or describe why you need that special case.

Comment: there is no special case. I justed hope to know if there is a way. I understand it and appreciate the answer.